# blender is not using the GPU as my graphics card

Tags: rendering

I have a 8.26GB total graphics card memory but blender is not using the GPU as my graphics card has 128mb of VRAM but my shared system memory is 8.13GB, is their any way or an addon to help me change this as I would like blender to render on my GPU rather than my CPU. Would appreciate any help.[image]

Comment: btw I did try to change in the settings but it keeps saying no compatible GPUs found

Comment: What kind of card do you have?

Comment: i have added a picture

Answer (score 3):

The intel 520 is an *integrated* graphics chip, which means it resides on, and shares power with, the CPU.  You're better off using CPU on this machine.

The total available memory is your 8GB RAM plus *128 MB* dedicated for video.